# In this situation, how to decrease the payout amount based on the "weighed" constituent parts?

Tags: optimization, finance

Couldn't think of a better way to explain it in the title, my bad.

This is a problem I'm running into in a programming project.
Here's the situation:

Say a partner is due to be paid $1000 for providing 100 leads or something. Lets say that 25% of the leads are from the US/UK (highly valuable), another 25% are from, say, Span (valuable, but not as much) and the rest are from Sierra Leone (not valuable).

I want to be able to assign weight to them so to speak, and subtract from the $1000 (that number is pre-determined based on a bunch of other things; I simply want to adjust it based on the quality of the leads)

I need to make a formula that takes these into account. If the partner only provides the poorest quality installs, I want to cut it down to like $200.

I'm not sure how to even tag this problem.

Comment: Basically wouldn't you just pay them say \$10 per highly valuable lead, \$6 per valuable, but not so much lead and \$2 per not valuable lead. This gives a maximum price of \$1000 for 100 leads and cuts it down to \$200 if all leads are of the poorest quality.

Comment: Won't those numbers change if the 1000 amount is changed, to, say $6,943.33 ?

Comment: Sure you just have to set to highest price at one hundredth of the total amount you're willing to pay and decrease the price for the lower quality products to some level you feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to assign point values based on where the leads are.  Maybe 3 points for the highest value leads, 2 for medium, 1 for low (pick the numbers to suit).  Now the requirement needs to be adjusted to 2000 points or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that an employee is supposed to receive $x$ dollars for $n$ top-quality leads, and that this amount is to be reduced when the leads are of poorer quality than desired.

Thus, each individual lead is valued at $\frac{x}{n}$ dollars (assuming it is top-quality).

If the leads collected are named $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_m$ (note that the number of leads actually collected, $m$, may not be equal to the number $n$ you are basing your starting scale on) then you could set the amount to be paid for these $n$ leads to be
$$\frac{x}{n}\sum_{i=1}^m\mathrm{weight}(\ell_i)$$
where the leads are assigned weights ranging between $0$ and $1$. These could be determined on a lead-by-lead basis, or you maybe you prefer to have a fixed list of values, say
$$\{0,\;0.2,\;0.5,\;0.8,\;1\}$$
that the weight of each lead must be chosen from.

If you want to ensure a lower bound on salaries, so that someone who collected $n$ bottom-quality leads would still get $y$ dollars (for some $y<x$), the simplest solution would be to scale the weights so that the worst leads are given a weight of $\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: This is a great answer, however it challenges my mind to come to terms with the question - "Why have I smoked so much pot in college?"